# How to vertically center text in button if text takes up two lines?

Tags: html, css

How would I go about vertically centering multiple lines of text in a button that has a specified width and height?

```
<a href="#">This text will take up two lines</a>

a {
    display: inline-block
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: not sure what you mean, but I think you need to add some line-height, or a margin-top:..%;.
could you give us a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `line-height`:

```
a { line-height: 50px; }
```

This only works if the text takes up one line. If you have to deal with mulitple lines, you could make use of `display: table-cell`:

```
a { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Comment: @miah, That's true. I just assumed that's the case, but yeah, maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

Add 
        vertical-align: middle; 
to your CSS.

Comment: Would I need to make the a tag display:inline-cell; ?

Answer (score 0):

it would be best to use % or em when dealing with line-height. Different browsers render text (size) differently; when you use % it adjusts auto accordingly.

```
a { line-height: 1.3em; }
```

Comment: this assumes one line of text only, which the OP states two lines of text in the problem.

Comment: Ahhhh. i guess i didn't read the whole question :/ 

a possible solution is to:
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle; (Linus already said this :) )